# How can I fix my custom keyboard to work properly?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

Every time I press the check button the keyboard understands that i've pressed it!

It makes no sense to give a user the wrong answer if s/he hasn't even typed anything in to the text field

So how can i block my check button to not recognise it if its the first thing pressed by the user....?

```
- (IBAction)btncheck:(id)sender {

NSString *answer = [_textbox.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

if ([answer isEqualToString:@"q"]) {
    // String is correct, resign keyboard
    _keyboard.hidden = YES;
    _textXclear.hidden = YES;
    //Perfect button
    [_closeone setHidden:NO];
    [_wrongone setHidden:YES];

}
else {
    // Was not correct.  Notify user, or just don't do anything
    [_wrongone setHidden:NO];

    // animation that shakes the image (qimage)


    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.03];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:0.15];
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:0];
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:YES]

    qimage.transform = CGAffineTransformMake(1.08, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1.);
    qimage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0,0);

}
```

And finally the else veritable is a animation that needs fixing, so what is the right way to animate a UIImage to buzz/vibrate/earthquake effect or shake from left to right when the user gets a wrong answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you check for an empty string first?

```
 if([answer isEqualToString:@""]) {
    //do nothing
} else {
    //do your stuff
    if ([answer isEqualToString:@"q"]) {
        // String is correct, resign keyboard
        _keyboard.hidden = YES;
        _textXclear.hidden = YES;
        //Perfect button
        [_closeone setHidden:NO];
        [_wrongone setHidden:YES];

    }
    else {
        // Was not correct.  Notify user, or just don't do anything
        [_wrongone setHidden:NO];

        // animation that shakes the image (qimage)


        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.03];
        [UIView setAnimationDelay:0.15];
        [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:0];
        [UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:YES]

        qimage.transform = CGAffineTransformMake(1.08, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1.);
        qimage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0,0);

    }
}
```